# Subview management within master/detail view in iOS (with ARC)

Tags: ios, uiview, master-detail

I have a master-detail controller for my app.  The master controller is a UITabBarController and each tab is a UITableViewController that contains different types of data.

I plan on having a main header / image on the main detail view but then need to add different subviews to the main detail view to detail specific information depending on which tab I am using.

I am currently adding the relevant subview in my

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Function like so:

```
UIViewController *subview = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemNotFoundViewController" bundle:nil];
subview.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 160, subview.view.frame.size.width, subview.view.frame.size.height);  
[self.detailViewController.view addSubview:subview.view];
```

However, I believe that this is a poor way of doing things - every time someone clicks on a table cell another subview will be thrown on top of the stack of previously added subviews, creating memory issues.

What I am wondering is, does ARC take care of this for me?  Is my approach passable?  and even if it is passable, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, no. ARC does not take care of this for you. It's not it's purpose to do that and even if it was, how could it know, that you don't want the previously added subviews anymore?
You have to remove those subviews yourself and **then** ARC will take care of deallocating them (if there are no other references to them).

Anyway that's not the way you're supposed to use a `UISplitViewController` (the master-detail view controller). As you noticed the split view controller handles two other view controllers. The master- and the detailViewController. In most cases the master view controller isn't changing while the app runs (it's content changes, but usually that's handled by a container view controller like `UINavigationController` which is assigned as the masterViewController), but the detail view controller does.

Instead of adding subviews to your existing detailViewController you should **replace** it by a new one. So you should create separate XIBs (what you've apparently done already) for all the view controllers that you want to present in the detail-section. And modify your code to

```
self.detailViewController = newDetailViewController; //newDetailViewController would be the vc you called subview in your code
```

instead of

```
[self.detailViewController.view addSubview:subview.view];
```

Edit: Notice that this assumes that your `detailViewController` property does 'the right things' when you set it's value. By default the `UISplitViewController` only has a property called `viewControllers` which is an `NSArray` in which the first object is the masterVC and the second is the detailVC.

Take a look at [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775) for an example of how to manage that.

Since you want to have a header view in all your detail view controllers you have various choice of achieving that (which may or may not be applicable in your case, depending on your design):

- add the header view to every details vc's XIB
- instead of creating many XIBs for all detailVCs, create a new custom `UIViewController` subclass that modifies it's content based on some parameters you give it, i.e. which tableViewCell was tapped by the user
- create a custom container view controller that manages two child view controllers, one for the headline and one for the content above it.

For more information about `UISplitViewController` and custom container view controller, please refer to:

[View Controller Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)

[Creating Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Comment: OK, I'm following - however, I changed the code `[self.detailViewController.view addSubview:subview.view];` to `[self.detailViewController setView:subview.view]`.  Does that work instead of reassigning the entire controller?

Comment: Maybe it does, maybe it doesn't. I know that's an awful answer, but the fact is, that you really really shouldn't do that. As Apple clearly stated on multiple occasions: A view controller owns and manages it's view, **don't take away it's view** or bad things will happen (i.e. grabbing it and putting it into another view controller). Take the time to read about the proper usage of a `UISplitViewController`, it will save you a lot of trouble in the long run. Apple also said, that they might start throwing exceptions in the future when you create an - what they call - inconsistent hierarchy.

Comment: OK.  Only reason I ask is because when replacing the entire controller, my view refuses to update, even when executing `[subviewController setNeedsDisplay]`.  Doing what I just asked about above actually refreshed the view properly.

Comment: Actually I wasn't precise enough, you can't just replace that line and everything is peachy. I've edited my answer and added a link to an example project of Apple about how to manage different detail view controllers. Again, if your detail view controllers don't do much fancy stuff, it might be sufficient two create just one custom view controller subclass to manage the different detail views. The XCode-Template `Master-Detail-Application` does that. Maybe you take a look at that too.

Answer (score 0):

No, ARC will not take of this for you, because detailViewController.view will keep a reference to its subviews. It's hard to say what approach is best without knowing more about what you're doing with these views. It would probably be better to just present the new view controller -- it will be deallocated after it's dismissed if you don't have a property pointing to it.

Comment: I basically just have two views for each tab - one is an "item not found in database" view, and another is a view that details everything there is to know about said item.  These views fit into a main content area that is a sub-area of my main detail view.